# How expect(stub.method) in sinon works?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, testing, sinon

I have a sinon's stub: `dummy = sinon.stub({foo: function() {}});`

In my test, I can use the following syntax:

```
expect(dummy.foo.calledOnce).to.be.false;
```

However, the following syntax does not work:

```
expect(dummy.foo).to.have.been.called;   // this and the following tests passed, 
                                         // but not what I expect
expect(dummy.foo).to.have.been.calledTwice;
expect(dummy.foo).to.have.been.calledThrice;
dummy.foo.should.have.been.called;
```

The syntax was copied from [here](https://github.com/domenic/sinon-chai). What is the right way to rewrite the expectation besides the first method?

Comment: did you actually call `dummy.foo()` ever? please paste your entire test case.

Comment: my bad. I should stop working late now. It's `sinon-chai` syntax and not `chai`. I just need to add `chai.use(sinon-chai)`